# Выделенный интернет

Tags: linux

Подключен интернет по выделенке. ОС убунту 11,04. Настроил все отлично пароль и логин, pppoconf, plog, ifconfig.Айпишники шлюзы и тд прописал правильно (проверял). Инт есть. Но вылезает надпись - проводное подключение разаорвано (но инт же есть). Аська и енекоторые сервисы убунты не работают (пишут что мол не в сети ты братан, НО Я ЖЕ В СЕТИ). В чем может быть проблема? Раньше же все работало......

Comment: то есть, пинги идут и в браузере открываются странички?

Comment: именно так оно и есть

Answer (score 1):

может фаервол? поставь пинговаться что нить пакетами по 1500 байт посмотри, когда появляется надпись пинги идут?
Попробуй вспомнить с каких пор перестало работать

Comment: Пинги проходят на отлично.